# How to set up WSO2 APIM 3.2 on LB

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

We are using WSO2 APIM 3.2 and MySQL 8.0.18 version. How to set up WSO2 APIM 3.2 on LB?

Comment: https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/3.2.0/install-and-setup/setup/setting-up-proxy-server-and-the-load-balancer/configuring-the-proxy-server-and-the-load-balancer/#configuring-the-proxy-server-and-the-load-balancer

Comment: Thanks for your response Pubci. I will let you know in case of any challenges.

Comment: Can we use the H/W LB for WSO2 in place of NGINX?

Comment: Yes, you can use F5. SHould work with other lbs also

Comment: Are there any different settings need to do for H/W LB?

Comment: No there aren't any